# Problemas ao passar 3 parâmetros via requisição AJAX -Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-core

Preciso passar 3 parâmetros para minha controller, mas os valores não chegam:

- PessoaContatoViewModel pessoaContatoViewModel: Parâmetro complexo (classe com propriedades);
- int formaContatoIdChange: Parâmetro simples inteiro;
- PessoaNatureza pessoaNatureza: Parâmetros do tipo enum.

  ```
  [HttpPost]
  [Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato")]
  public IActionResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] 
  PessoaContatoViewModel pessoaContatoViewModel, int formaContatoIdChange, 
  PessoaNatureza pessoaNatureza)
  {
      //ViewBag.indice_new = indice;
      //return        
      PartialView("~/Views/Pessoa/PessoaContato/_PessoaContatoAdd.cshtml", 
      _pessoaContatoAppService.CreateNew(pessoaNatureza, formaContatoId));
     return null;
  }

  var formaContatoIdPrevious = "0";
  $("#div-contatos .row").bind("click", ".sel-forma-contato", function (e) 
   {
  //Forma de contato selecionada antes de alterar
  formaContatoIdPrevious = $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-forma- 
  contato').val(); 
  }).on("change", ".sel-forma-contato", function (e) {
  //Pegar Índice da row
  var rowIndice = $(this).closest('.row').index();

  //Pegando os valores dos Fields
  var pessoaNatureza = $('#pessoaNatureza').val();
  var formaContatoIdChange = $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-forma- 
   contato').val(); //Forma de contato selecionada depois de alterar


  var pessoaContatoViewModel = {
      Id: $(this).closest('.row').find('.hid-id').val(),
      PessoaId: $(this).closest('.row').find('.hid-pessoaId').val(),
      FormaContatoId: parseInt(formaContatoIdPrevious),
      FormaContatoTipoId: $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-contato-tipo').val(),
      Contato: $(this).closest('.row').find('.txt-contato').val(),
      Observacao: $(this).closest('.row').find('.txt-observacao').val(),
      ContatoPrincipal: $(this).closest('.row').find('.ckb-contato-principal').is(":checked")
  };

  //Telefone, Celular ou Fax
  switch (formaContatoIdPrevious) {
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
          var pessoaContatoChamadaViewModel = {
              ChamadaTipo: $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-chamada-tipo').val(),
              OperadoraChamadaId: $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-operadora-chamada').val(),
              CodigoDDI: $(this).closest('.row').find('txt-ddi').val(),
              CodigoDDD: $(this).closest('.row').find('txt-ddd').val(),
              Ramal: $(this).closest('.row').find('txt-ramal').val()
          };
          pessoaContatoViewModel.PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel = {};
          pessoaContatoViewModel.PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel = pessoaContatoChamadaViewModel;

          break;

      case "5": //E-mail
          var pessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel = {
              UsarParaNotaFiscalEmitida: $(this).closest('.row').find('ckb-usar-nf-emitida').is(":checked"),
              UsarParaOrdemCompra: $(this).closest('.row').find('ckb-usar-ordem-compra').is(":checked"),
              UsarParaPedidoVenda: $(this).closest('.row').find('ckb-usar-pedido-venda').is(":checked"),
              UsarParaMarketing: $(this).closest('.row').find('ckb-usar-marketing').is(":checked")
          };
          pessoaContatoViewModel.PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel = {};
          pessoaContatoViewModel.PessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel = pessoaContatoCorreioEletronicoViewModel;

          break;

      case "7": //Blog e Mídia Social
      case "8":
          var pessoaContatoMidiaSocialViewModel = {
              MidiaSocialId: $(this).closest('.row').find('sel-midia-social').val()
          };
          pessoaContatoViewModel.PessoaContatoMidiaSocialViewModel = {};
          pessoaContatoViewModel.PessoaContatoMidiaViewModel = pessoaContatoMidiaSocialViewModel;
          break;
  }

  var dados = { pessoaContatoViewModel: pessoaContatoViewModel, formaContatoIdChange: formaContatoIdChange, pessoaNatureza: pessoaNatureza };

  $.ajax({
      url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato",
      type: "POST",
      data: JSON.stringify({ pessoaContatoViewModel: pessoaContatoViewModel, formaContatoIdChange: formaContatoIdChange, pessoaNatureza: pessoaNatureza }),
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (result) {
          formaContatoIdPrevious = "0";
          alert('ok');
      },
      error: function () {
          formaContatoIdPrevious = "0";
          alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
      }
  });

  formaContatoIdPrevious = "0";
  ```

  });

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que está errado?

Comment: Sera que é porque está usando o mesmo nome de parâmetros e variáveis.

Comment: O que está apresentando em `Network` no DevTools do Chrome, por exemplo? Como está sendo enviado? E que resposta ele está retornando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo sua chamada do AJAX, você está enviado algo assim:

```
 public class PessoaDTO {

        public PessoaContatoViewModel PessoaContatoViewModel { get; set; }
        public int FormaContatoIdChange { get; set; }
        public PessoaNatureza PessoaNatureza { get; set; }

    }
```

Tente isso então:

```
   [HttpPost()]
    [Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContrato")]
    public IActionResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] PessoaDTO pessoaDTO) {
        return Ok();
    }
```